# Wrong count when executed but response is 1 when using querying database directly

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I'm always getting response as 0 for this count but is 1 when I query DB straight. What am I missing here?

```js
const getItemsCount = (db, applicationId, typeId) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const existsStatement = `SELECT COUNT(ITEMIDENTIFIER) AS ITCOUNT
            FROM LISTITEMS
            WHERE WORKLISTREFERENCEIDENTIFIER = '${applicationId}'
            AND TYPEID = '${typeId}'`;
        
          db.executeQuery(existsStatement)
            .then((result) => {
               resolve(parseInt(result[0].ITCOUNT, 10));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              reject(error);
            });
        });
        
          populate(applicationId, data) {
            const ITM = this;
        
            ITM.populatePromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
              if (!data || !data.typeId) {
                reject(new Error('Body parameters missing'));
              }
        
               await queries.getWorklistItemsCount(ITM.db, applicationId, data.typeId).then((result)=>{
                 resolve(result)
              }) 
        })
        }
```

Comment: Check the value of  `existsStatement` - you are probably not submitting the values you think you are.

Comment: Hi Jen R the values are being received on getItemsCount but i'm not sure if they are sent cz the result should be 1 instead of zero and response status is 200

Comment: That's why you need to look at the exact string that's getting submitted to the DB.  Put it in an alert or write it to the screen and look at it.

Comment: Hi @JenR Thanks, finally got it right, some values on body parameters were incorrectly passed